Создание системы HTML файлов, как автономный архив для постов VK
Я новичок в теме коддинга, но знаю как примерно создать сайт. И проблема в том что мне нужно создать сайт-архив для постов VK, чтобы его можно было править из HTML файла, а не из VS. Под словами править я подразумеваю добавление/удаление глав архива (единственное до чего я дошел, это до создания отдельных HTML файлов вручную), а так же добавление/удаление постов VK посредством ссылок или куда более простым способом.
Первое что я пробовал, просто переносить код для вставки в свой HTML файл. Но это касается создания и правки HTML кода изнутри. От меня же требуется создать автономный "архив" без использования HTML кодировки дабы изменить или добавить пост/раздел. Простой как пробковая доска и булавка, но в виде автономного "архива" на ПК для информации с постов VK.


Простой как пробковая доска и булавка,

... космический корабль. :)
Ты говоришь о системе управления контентом.
Их много разных. От простых файловых, до более функциональных с использованием баз данных.
Если для локального пользования, то возможно тебе подойдёт уже мёртвый textolite или иная файловая CMS (в гуглояндексах много чего можно найти).

То есть банальными словами, легче человека научить делать ctrl C+V уже на имеющейся VS.  Ладно, придется работать с тем что имею.

@TegZero Не знаю кто такой "VS" в твоём понимании, но управление контентом в CMS доступно любой домохозяйке чуть умнее обезьяны. А у того же тестолита, что я показал даже демка доступна. Подсмотри на неё.

Да, извиняюсь за неясность Visual Studio Code (VSCode) так наверное было бы понятнее. И я проверил текстолит, это конечно да, совсем упрощенная и понятная интерпретация кодировки HTML файлов. Этот сайт позволяет облегчить работу с уже имеющимися фалами, я же решил облегчить себе "копипасту" с ВК загружая скрипт с последующим выведением поста на HTML файл. И же искал скрипт позволяющий скопированный мною скрипт, вставлять в HTML, с самого сайта. P.S. - Если бы это было для человека знающего что бывают такие сайты, я бы не задумывался об упрощения "копипасты".
